# Error creating a custom FXML loader in Spring

Tags: java, spring, javafx

I've been trying to move my JavaFx application to Spring to make use of dependency injecton. The project has become too big to move items between classes manually.

The code does not show any red error highlights on my netbeans IDE, but when I run I keep getting this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'homeController' defined in class wakiliproject.controllerinjection.SampleAppFactory: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public wakiliproject.controllerinjection.controllers.HomeController wakiliproject.controllerinjection.SampleAppFactory.homeController() throws java.io.IOException] threw exception; nested exception is javafx.fxml.LoadException: Base location is undefined.
```

I have it like this:

```
public class SampleApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context
                = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(SampleAppFactory.class);

        Group box = new Group();
        HomeController homeController = context.getBean(HomeController.class);
        box.getChildren().add(homeController.getView());

        Scene scene = new Scene(box, 600, 200);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("JFX2.0 Sprung");
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

--

```
@Configuration
public class SampleAppFactory {

    @Bean
    public HomeController homeController() throws IOException {
        return (HomeController) loadController("/resources/fxml/Home.fxml");
    }

    protected Object loadController(String url) throws IOException {
        InputStream fxmlStream = null;
        try {
            fxmlStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(url);
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
            loader.load(fxmlStream);
            return loader.getController();
        } finally {
            if (fxmlStream != null) {
                fxmlStream.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

--

```
public class HomeController {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane view;

    public AnchorPane getView() {
        return view;
    }
}
```

An extract of the FXML file looks something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<AnchorPane fx:id="view" prefHeight="654.0" prefWidth="900.0" styleClass="AnchorPane" visible="true" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2" fx:controller="wakiliproject.controllerinjection.controllers.HomeController">
    <children>
        <Pane id="wrapperPane" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="700.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Pane id="top" layoutX="-1.0" layoutY="3.0" prefWidth="879.0" styleClass="appNav" visible="true">
                    <children>
                        <HBox id="HBox" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="12.0" layoutY="6.0" spacing="0.0">
                            <children>
                                <Label prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="titleBarHome" />
                                <Label prefHeight="32.0" prefWidth="32.0" styleClass="titleBarPublisher" />
                            </children>
                        </HBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to set the location of your FXML file on the `FXMLLoader`. This can be the case if, for example, your FXML file requires resolving relative locations. Using the `FXMLLoader.load(URL)` method does not set the location. Try

```
protected Object loadController(String url) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(url));
    loader.load();
    return loader.getController();
}
```

instead of the current implementation you have.

Incidentally, have you looked at [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) as a (much more lightweight) alternative to Spring for dependency injection in JavaFX?

Comment: Thanks for your response @James_D. Just noticed that if I link a node to some css file, that's when the project fails. What may be the problem? The project compiles when I remove the style sheet files.

Comment: Update your question showing the code that makes it fail. Does it fail with/without my changes to the `loadController(...)` method?